# Access $locale in angular.module('xxx').value

Tags: angularjs, date-format, angular-ui

I'm using angular-ui:s date directive (uiDate) and need to configure it. I can do that like this:

```
app.value('ui.config', {
    date: {
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', // <-- I want to use $locale.shortDateFormat
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: false
    }
});
```

where `app` is my application module.

What I would like to do is to define the `dateFormat` from angulars $locale object, which using i18n contains my cultures specific date-formats.

The `value` property of app does not seem to have access to $locale at that point though, so I'm feeling that this is the wrong way to do it.

How can I provide the dateformat and other stuff from the locale-object to my directives, without having to modify the source code of ui-date (since it's an external dependency of my project).

I can solve this by setting this object in my controllers, but that's not what I want. This is a configuration that should work in all my controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularUI is currently undergoing a bit of refactoring which changes this slightly.

Anyway, you can always pass the dateFormat property to uiDate inline, it will be merged with the global configuration. I don't know if it's possible to set .value() from within app.run as was suggested though, but I would think `.value()` is supposed to be easily overridable. You can even try modifying the object since theoretically the reference would be preserved (depending on when the directive injection function is executed).

Sorry it's not more helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So it is not possible to have a fresh $locale instance when I configure a module?

Comment: my solution right now is to get these global options from a service, which seems like overkill, since I need to explicitly set the options for each scope anyway.

Comment: Why do you need to set the options for each scope? Are they unique or are you just saying you have to pass it in at every controller level? If they are NOT unique, just declare the configuration on the `$rootScope`. Alternatively you can create an options-generator method on the `$rootScope` that adds any unique options for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bootstrap` to do that. You don't even need to be "inside" angular to use that.

More about bootstrap: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap and http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap

Just a note ... When navigating on the site, set the version to 1.2 so you can see the comments. It's very helpfull.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="result">

</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var locale = angular.bootstrap(function ($locale) { }).get('$locale'),
    html = '';


for(var i = 0; i < locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH.length; i++) {
    html += '<li>' + locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.MONTH[i] + '</li>';
}

$('#result').html(html);
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/82aRW/